# Hibernate Uppercase

Tags: hibernate, uppercase

When I try to map a table in my database with a bean in my application using hibernate xml mapping files ...hbm.xml I obtein the fallowing resulteverytime I run the app:

> INFO: table not found: especies
>   Initial SessionFactory creation
>   failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException:
>   Missing table: especies

I've realize the problem is that hibernate doesn´t recognize my table because I have it in lowercase in the db.

I realize about this because when I change the property hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto (placed in the hibernate.cfg.xml, I have it in validate mode) in create and drop mode it works because it create a new table all in uppercase(included column names) and let the old one in lowercase with no change.

I assume this is something about the hibernate conguration, so...

How can I change the hibernate configuration to understand my lowercase configuration of the db?

Comment: Nop it is derby(Jave db embbebed)

Answer (score 3):

By default, Hibernate uses the [`DefaultNamingStrategy`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/cfg/DefaultNamingStrategy.html), which uses mixed-case database object names. This often doesn't work well. It provides an alternative called [`ImprovedNamingStrategy`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/cfg/ImprovedNamingStrategy.html), which uses underscores rather than mixed case, which is often a better fit for the database.

How you configure this depends on your setup, but you haven't said if you're using annotations or XML config.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I'm using xml config. I will be grateful if you tell me how can I configure this.

Comment: @Diana: See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-namingstrategy @skaffman: +1

Comment: Working links as of version 3.6: [DefaultNamingStrategy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/DefaultNamingStrategy.html) and [ImprovedNamingStrategy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/ImprovedNamingStrategy.html). I couldn't find a stable version generic link any more.

Comment: one can just enable it by **adding `<property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />`** to your **`persistence.xml`** (as mentioned here: http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/tips-and-tricks/implementing-a-custom-namingstrategy-with-hibernate/)